# How to use "zypper info" with a specific version of a package

Tags: linux, package, require, rpm, zypper

I want to query the requires of a package using zypper info:

```
zypper info --requires my_package
```

This does not work with a specific version like :

```
zypper info --requires my_package-1.2.0
```

Capabilities seem not to be supported by the "info" command of zypper but
they work fine when using zypper install (e.g. zypper in my_package=1.2.0)

Is there any way to retrieve the required packages of a given package/version
by using zypper ?

I could also use rpm, but only when the rpm is accessible in the file system.
Maybe some packages are only integrated as zypper services.

Any help is appreciated.